# Format Date to String To Be Passed to API

Tags: angular, angular-http, ng-bootstrap, angular-forms

I need to pass this date to an api and it needs to be a string. How can i do it since i'm using ng-bootstrap datepicker?  when i did `date: this.date.toString()`, it returns [object] [Object]. I want it to be a string

```
<div class="input-group col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="date" required>
        <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
 </div>
```

> ts

```
this.date = this.myForm.get('date').value

date: this.date.toString(),
```

Comment: Actually  you are sending the all form date in API. or only the date data?

Comment: @Ajmalsha. Well the date comes from the form. My problem is that i returns [object] [object]

Comment: so your requrement is to convert the form data to string . is it?

Comment: @Ajmalsha. Yes a string

Comment: check the answer. is this satisfy your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I did this.  `this.date = this.parserFormatter.format(this.myForm.get('date').value)`
AND I imported it in `import {NgbDateParserFormatter} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`